# Wordpress: Removing shortcodes from search results page

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Been researching on this issue. Found lots of advice but none that seem to work or that applies to my site. In the search results page, my website displays shortcodes from plugins as code. I'd like to hide this code from being displayed.

[image]

This is the code from my search.php page

```html
<?php
/**
 * Search results page
 *
 * @package shaka-pt
 */

get_header();

$shaka_sidebar = get_field( 'sidebar', (int) get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) );

if ( ! $shaka_sidebar ) {
    $shaka_sidebar = 'left';
}

get_template_part( 'template-parts/page-header' );

?>

    <div id="primary" class="content-area  container">
        <div class="row">
            <main id="main" class="site-main  masonry  col-xs-12<?php echo 'left' === $shaka_sidebar ? '  col-lg-9  col-lg-push-3' : ''; ?><?php echo 'right' === $shaka_sidebar ? '  col-lg-9' : ''; ?>" role="main">
                <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

                    <div class="grid  js-pt-masonry  row">
                        <div class="grid-sizer  col-xs-12  col-sm-6  col-lg-4"></div>
                        <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
                        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                            <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'search' ); ?>

                        <?php endwhile; ?>
                    </div>

                    <?php
                        the_posts_pagination( array(
                            'prev_text' => '<i class="fa  fa-long-arrow-left"></i>',
                            'next_text' => '<i class="fa  fa-long-arrow-right"></i>',
                        ) );
                    ?>

                <?php else : ?>

                    <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' ); ?>

                <?php endif; ?>
            </main>

            <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/sidebar', 'blog' ); ?>

        </div>
    </div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Here is the code from the template-parts/content-search.php

```html
<?php
/**
 * The template part for displaying results in search pages.
 *
 * Learn more: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
 *
 * @package shaka-pt
 */

$blog_columns = get_theme_mod( 'blog_columns', 6 );

?>

<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class( array( 'grid-item', 'col-xs-12', 'col-sm-6', esc_attr( sprintf( 'col-lg-%s', $blog_columns ) ) ) ); ?>>
    <!-- Featured Image -->
    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
        <header class="hentry__header">
            <a class="hentry__featured-image" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'post-thumbnail', array( 'class' => 'img-fluid' ) ); ?>
            </a>
        </header><!-- .hentry__header -->
    <?php endif; ?>

    <!-- Content Box -->
    <div class="hentry__content  entry-content">
        <!-- Date -->
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><time class="hentry__date" datetime="<?php the_time( 'c' ); ?>"><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></time></a>
        <!-- Author -->
        <span class="hentry__author"><i class="fa  fa-user"></i> <?php echo esc_html__( 'By' , 'shaka-pt' ) . ' ' . get_the_author(); ?></span>
        <!-- Content -->
        <?php the_title( sprintf( '<h2 class="hentry__title"><a href="%s" rel="bookmark">', esc_url( get_permalink() ) ), '</a></h2>' ); ?>
        <p>
            <?php echo wp_kses_post( get_the_excerpt() ); ?>
        </p>
        <p>
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink() ); ?>" class="more-link"><?php printf( esc_html__( 'Read more %s', 'shaka-pt' ), the_title( '<span class="screen-reader-text">', '</span>', false ) ); ?></a>
        </p>
        <?php if ( has_category() || comments_open( get_the_ID() ) ) : ?>
            <div class="hentry__meta  meta">
                <!-- Categories -->
                <?php if ( has_category() ) : ?>
                    <span class="meta__item  meta__item--categories"><?php the_category( ' ' ); ?></span>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <!-- Comments -->
                <?php if ( comments_open( get_the_ID() ) ) : // Only show comments count if the comments are open. ?>
                    <span class="meta__item  meta__item--comments"><a href="<?php comments_link(); ?>"><?php ShakaHelpers::pretty_comments_number(); ?></a></span>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div><!-- .hentry__meta -->
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div><!-- .hentry__content -->
</article><!-- #post-## -->
```

Comment: Send us a screenshot, what does it mean. Where did they come from, why are they displayed, do they come from the content of the post? What does hide mean? Remove  them?

Comment: edited my question and added a screenshot of the search results page

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing those shortcodes come from the posts that appear in the search results, assuming the red text is the excerpt.

You can strip these shortcodes before passing it
using [`strip_shortcodes()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/strip_shortcodes/)

Using your code from `template-parts/content.php` inside your content if else statement you make a call to `the_content()`, which returns your full content including shortcodes. You could try using the following code:

```
strip_shortcodes(
    the_content( sprintf(
        esc_html__( 'Read more %s', 'shaka-pt' ),
        the_title( '<span class="screen-reader-text">"', '" 
        </span>', false )
    ) );
);
```

This should be your new content for `template-parts/content.php`

```html
<?php
/**
 * Template part for displaying posts.
 *
 * @package shaka-pt
 */

$blog_columns = get_theme_mod( 'blog_columns', 6 );

?>

<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class( array( 'grid-item', 'col-xs-12', 'col-sm-6', esc_attr( sprintf( 'col-lg-%s', $blog_columns ) ) ) ); ?>>
    <!-- Featured Image -->
    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
        <header class="hentry__header">
            <a class="hentry__featured-image" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'post-thumbnail', array( 'class' => 'img-fluid' ) ); ?>
            </a>
        </header><!-- .hentry__header -->
    <?php endif; ?>

    <!-- Content Box -->
    <div class="hentry__content  entry-content">
        <!-- Date -->
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><time class="hentry__date" datetime="<?php the_time( 'c' ); ?>"><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></time></a>
        <!-- Author -->
        <span class="hentry__author"><i class="fa  fa-user"></i> <?php echo esc_html__( 'By' , 'shaka-pt' ) . ' ' . get_the_author(); ?></span>
        <!-- Content -->
        <?php the_title( sprintf( '<h2 class="hentry__title"><a href="%s" rel="bookmark">', esc_url( get_permalink() ) ), '</a></h2>' ); ?>
        <?php
        $shaka_is_excerpt = ( 1 === (int) get_option( 'rss_use_excerpt', 0 ) );
        if ( $shaka_is_excerpt ) : ?>
            <p>
                <?php echo strip_shortcodes(wp_kses_post( get_the_excerpt())); ?>
            </p>
            <p>
                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink() ); ?>" class="more-link"><?php printf( esc_html__( 'Read more %s', 'shaka-pt' ), the_title( '<span class="screen-reader-text">', '</span>', false ) ); ?></a>
            </p>
        <?php else :
            /* translators: %s: Name of current post */
            strip_shortcodes(
                the_content( sprintf(
                   esc_html__( 'Read more %s', 'shaka-pt' ),
                   the_title( '<span class="screen-reader-text">"', '" 
                   </span>', false )
                ) );
            );
        endif;
        ?>
        <div class="hentry__meta  meta">
            <!-- Categories -->
            <?php if ( has_category() ) : ?>
                <span class="meta__item  meta__item--categories"><?php the_category( ' ' ); ?></span>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <!-- Comments -->
            <?php if ( comments_open( get_the_ID() ) ) : // Only show comments count if the comments are open. ?>
                <span class="meta__item  meta__item--comments"><a href="<?php comments_link(); ?>"><?php ShakaHelpers::pretty_comments_number(); ?></a></span>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div><!-- .hentry__meta -->
    </div><!-- .hentry__content -->
</article><!-- .hentry -->
```

Comment: Hi Nick, yes I believe they are excerpts. How and where do I add this strip_shortcodes() function ?

Comment: We need to see the code from the template-parts/content.php file. I suspect it is using the_content() to render out the content to the browser.

Comment: thanks Nick, just added the code from the template-parts/content.php

Comment: See my answer for your new `template-parts/content.php` file

Comment: Thanks Nick, Unfortunately it did not work. Nothing changed

Comment: do you have a link to your website so I can take a closer look?

Comment: Great! Could you try the new content I provided in my answer

Comment: Hi Nick, looks like we have to modify the code in content-search.php instead of content.php. I edited the code to show the content-search.php. Could you tell me how and where to insert your code in that new php code?

Answer (score 0):

Once I had the same problem, it inserted shortcodes that I doesn't even used on my site, it was a "feature" of the theme... If I switched off the not used plugins, it looked like exactly this on the search result page. Don't know why exaclty on that page...:) My problem has been solved by editing and deleting this shortcodes from a search_result.php in my child theme.

Answer (score 0):

Try this   : add this in your theme's functions.php, additionally you would wrap the strip_shortcodes in if statement so that it runs only when you need

```
// remove shortcode from excerpt
     

function remove_shortcode_from_excerpt($content) {
   
    $content = strip_shortcodes( $content );
      
     return $content;
}
 
add_filter('the_excerpt', 'remove_shortcode_from_excerpt');
```

Comment: thanks, but unfortunately that didn't change anything.